# Passing parameters to reduce function

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have read [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reduce.asp) article, but I don't seem to understand JavaScript's reduce syntax correctly. How can I pass additional parameters to custom reducer function?

**Calling reducer function.**

```
data = Object.values(data.reduce(reducer, {}));
```

**Reducer function example.**

```
const reducer = (acc, cur) => {
if (somethingIsTrue) {
return acc;
}
};
```

Right now it is working like it should, but let's say that I'm calling reducer function and I want to pass simple variable that contains "Hello World" in away that function doesn't see it as an argument. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you be more specific like **what you have tried?**, **Actual output you got** and **expected output?**

Comment: The parameters `acc` and `cur` are passed implicitly, if they are the only ones you need. If you want to pass more parameters, you have to explicitly pass all of them like this: `data.reduce((acc, cur, your-third-param) => reducer(acc, cur, your-third-param), {})`

Comment: It is a tip of learning. Different people have different mindset. Sometime you may find some resource is not easy to understand for you. You may try to find other resource then and don't stuck in one resource. For example. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do function composition to "build up" something called an higher order function. Basically the idea is to create a function that returns a "child function", which will have access to the parent function's variables.

```js
// Parent function (getReducer)
function getReducer(stringToAppend) {
    
    // Child function (reducer)
    function reducer(acc, curr) {
        // Child function has access to parent's variables (in this case stringToAppend)
        acc[curr] = stringToAppend + curr
        return acc
    }
    
    return reducer
}

const data = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
const result = data.reduce(getReducer("Hello World "), {})
console.log('result :>> ', result);
```

In console:

```
result :>>  {
  '0': 'Hello World 0',
  '1': 'Hello World 1',
  '2': 'Hello World 2',
  '3': 'Hello World 3',
  '4': 'Hello World 4',
  '5': 'Hello World 5',
  '6': 'Hello World 6',
  '7': 'Hello World 7',
  '8': 'Hello World 8',
  '9': 'Hello World 9'
}
```

I used the `function` syntax as I found it more verbose and explicit for explaining this. You could of course utilize arrow functions. Using arrow syntax the function could look as simple as:

```
function getReducer (stringToAppend) {
    return (acc, curr) => {
        acc[curr] = stringToAppend + curr
        return acc
    }
}
```